# Aggreagation on Mongo c# driver with not null field does not filter

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am doing an aggregation in Mongo and I cannot get the expected results; 
I want to count those with a null column and those with not null but apparently 
{ "$ne" : ["$RequestedOn", null] } is coming always as true.

I cannot really see where the problem is.
This is the data in the collection

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cf03445667a09b17f661ef"),
    "Name" : "User1 Test1",
    "AccountRef" : "AccountRef1",
    "Voucher" : "Voucher1",    
    "Email" : "AccountRef1@server.ie",
    "CampaignId" : ObjectId("56c752d439bac5655eec7fb7")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cf034c5667a09b17f661f0"),
    "Name" : "User2 Test2",
    "AccountRef" : "AccountRef2",
    "Voucher" : "Voucher2",
    "Email" : "AccountRef1@server.ie",
    "CampaignId" : ObjectId("56c752d439bac5655eec7fb7")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cf03565667a09b17f661f1"),
    "Name" : "User3 Test3",
    "AccountRef" : "AccountRef3",
    "Voucher" : "Voucher3",
    "GuidLink" : "7f079244-d94f-5e4a-8096-59b6df3ef64f",
    "Email" : "AccountRef1@server.ie",
    "CampaignId" : ObjectId("56c752d439bac5655eec7fb7")
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cf035e5667a09b17f661f2"),
    "Name" : "User4 Test4",
    "AccountRef" : "AccountRef4",
    "Voucher" : "Voucher4",
    "Email" : "AccountRef1@server.ie",
    "RequestedOn" : ISODate("2016-02-29T22:49:20.201Z"),
    "CampaignId" : ObjectId("56c752d439bac5655eec7fb7")
}
```

And this is how I build the query

```
var wlUsers=Database.Collection;
var cs = wlUsers.AsQueryable()
.Where(wl => wl.CampaignId == id)
.Select(p=> new { id = p.CampaignId, p.RequestedOn})
.GroupBy(wl => wl.id)
.Select(g => new CampaignStatistics{
    ExistingCustomers = g.Count(),                        
    TotalOrdered = g.Sum(w => w.RequestedOn.HasValue ? 1 :0),
    LastOrder = g.Max(w => w.RequestedOn),
    FirstOrder = g.Min(w => w.RequestedOn),
    Last24hOrders = g.Sum(w => 
        w.RequestedOn > DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)?1:0),
});
```

The result is

```
{
    "ExistingCustomers" : 4,
    "TotalOrdered" : 4,
    "LastOrder" : ISODate("2016-02-29T22:49:20.201Z"),
    "FirstOrder" : ISODate("2016-02-29T22:49:20.201Z"),
    "Last24hOrders" : 4
}
```

But it should be

```
{
    "ExistingCustomers" : 4,
    "TotalOrdered" : 1,
    "LastOrder" : ISODate("2016-02-29T22:49:20.201Z"),
    "FirstOrder" : ISODate("2016-02-29T22:49:20.201Z"),
    "Last24hOrders" : 0
}
```

So the totalOrdered has to be 1 and the 'Last24hOrders' = 0.

Also I am new on Mongo so I'll appreciate any tips advises on how to build these projections

Answer (score 1):

I will suspect this line

```
      TotalOrdered = g.Sum(w => w.RequestedOn.HasValue ? 1 :0),
```

try to change to:

```
     TotalOrdered = g.Sum(w => (w.RequestedOn.HasValue && w.RequestedOn.Value > DateTime.Min)  ? 1 :0)
```

Answer (score 1):

thx profesor79
I kind of sorted that way. This is how I did it

```
var project = agg.Project(r =>
    new{
        id = r.CampaignId,
        Last24H = r.RequestedOn.Value > DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1) ? 1 : 0,
        HasRequested = (r.RequestedOn.Value > new DateTime() ? 1 : 0),  //for some reason has value does not work (it is always true)
        Date = r.RequestedOn});

var match = project.Match(p => p.id == id);

var group = match.Group(
    r => r.id, 
    g => new CampaignStatistics{
            ExistingCustomers = g.Count(),
            TotalOrdered = g.Sum(p => p.HasRequested),
            LastOrder = g.Max(w => w.Date),
            FirstOrder = g.Min(w => w.Date),
            Last24HOrders = g.Sum(p => p.Last24H)});
```